# Hash table search function using Vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a hashtable using vectors, or would be it best to use a table with a struct ?

```
vector<int>*hashtable = new vector<int>[m];

    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        temp = T1[i] % m;
        hashtable[temp].push_back(T1[i]);


    for (int i = 0; i <= T2[0]; i++){
        valuefound = 0;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = hashtable[i].begin(); it != hashtable[i].end(); ++it){
        if(T2[i+1] == *it){
            T3HS[i] = i;
            valuefound = 1;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Wha not simply using one of the existing hashtables like `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: because this is how I have to do it...without using std::map or std::unordered_map

Comment: As the previous commenter said, try to use an associative container. The way you are trying to implement the hash is neither good C++ style in my opinion nor efficient I think. Chances are you won't beat an existing library in performance and I think you should maybe do a training or work a good C++ book. Maybe try another approach?

Comment: @Expert Sounds like a silly restriction. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Note: Asking about homework is not a bad thing (much rather you ask than fail) but it's useful for us to know because it often changes how the question will be answered. There are things that must be done for school that would raise eyebrows, if not outright laughter and employment termination, in industry.

Comment: Well I am probably allowed to use an associative container, but how would that help me ? I am pretty sure my hashtable is working, its the way I am searching in it. I am just trying to learn by doing it myself withtout std::map etc

Comment: Memory leak here: `vector<int>*hashtable = new vector<int>[m];` Recommend using `vector<vector<int>hashtable(M);` instead and letting variable scope deal with the memory management.

Comment: Memory leak here as well: `int *T3HS = new int[T2[0]];`. `vector<int>` probably the best solution.

Comment: My search function look good ? I changed the vector hashtable to your recommendation, still same problem

Comment: Those suggestions won't solve the search bug. They just clear up some memory problems you would run into later.

Answer (score 0):

The question can be rephrased better as: there are two values that exist in both tables. It seems like you're trying to make T3HS hold indices of found elements.

Your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= T2[0]; i++){
}
```

To loop through vectors, I always use:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= T2.length(); i++){
}
```

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have a `length()` member function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: yes this is what I am trying to do. T3HS to hold indices of found elements, if not found I put -1. T2.length() or T2[0] is the same thing

Comment: [If possible use a range-based `for` loop.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) much harder to accidentally screw up.

Comment: T2 is not a vector, its a *table

Answer (score 0):

There are `N` or `N+1` hash table vectors, but you're only looking at `T2[0]` of them.

Incidentally, your search pattern loop will access past the end of the `T2` array with `T2[i+1]` when `i` is `T2[0]`.

Comment: How I see it is this way: T2[0] tells me to search for 4 numbers.

Comment: and my second for should look trough the first row of my vector.

Comment: Then when that is done, my first loop will iterate to the second row and look trough it until it finds matches elements with the one im looking for. etc. isnt this how it should be ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a while to get there so bear with me.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    temp = T1[i] % m;
    hashtable[temp].push_back(T1[i]);
}
```

Sorts the numbers into bins and stores them. Groovy. No problems here. But this:

```
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = hashtable[i].begin(); it != hashtable[i].end(); ++it)
    {
        if (T2[i + 1] == *it)
        {
            T3HS[i] = i;
            valuefound = 1;
        }
    }
```

Doesn't look in those bins for the numbers. It's looking all over the place. What you want to do is look in the right bin.

```
    int searchval = T2[i + 1]; // cache the number we're looking for. Easier debugging
    int binindex = searchval % m; // get the bin for this number
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    // now we look just in that one bin.
    for (it = hashtable[binindex].begin(); it != hashtable[binindex].end(); ++it)
    {
        if (searchval == *it)
        {
            T3HS[i] = i;
            valuefound = 1;
            break;// found it . Stop looking.
        }
    }
```

After this there are a ton of little improvements:

Start with the range-based for loop

```
    int searchval = T2[i + 1];
    int binindex = searchval % m;
    for (int val: hashtable[binindex])
    {
        if (searchval == val)
        {
            T3HS[i] = i;
            valuefound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Next, cut the search algorithm out and put it in its own function. This gets rid of chaff like `valuefound`. The function returns whether or not the value was found.  A function should do one thing and one thing only. Sometimes that one thing is aggregating a number of other functions. For one thing, consider whty you are building the hash table inside a search function. Makes more sense to have a function to make a hash table and another to search it. Both functions do one and only one thing. As an added bonus, splitting them up means you can re-use the hash table for multiple searches.

```
bool search (int searchval, vector<int>*hashtable, int m)
{
    int binindex = searchval % m;
    for (int val: hashtable[binindex])
    {
        if (searchval == val)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and call it

```
for (int i = 0; i <= T2[0]; i++)
{
    if (search(T2[i+1], hashtable, m))
    {
        T3HS[i] = i;
    }
    else
    {
        T3HS[i] = -1;
    }
}
```

Then you range a little further out and fill all of the memory leaks like

```
int *T3HS = new int[T2[0]];
```

and

```
vector<int>*hashtable = new vector<int> [m];
```

with `vectors`. Never `new` unless you absolutely have to because everything you `new` you have to `delete`, and figuring out when and where to delete things can be a pain in the butt. Let the compiler do it for you.

Next up, you have a grouping of functions and data that describe the hash table. Might as well bundle all of that up into a `hashtable` class.

And finally think on how you are using `hashtable`. You want to make it easy and obvious. You don't want a page-long comment explaining that `T2[0]` contains the length of the list and must always be no greater than one less than the length of the list. You just know someone is going to read it wrong. You sucked 1201ProgramAlarm into making that mistake, and they're no dummy. You are much better off with another variable that contains the length or, once again, use a `vector` because it knows how long it is.

The easier you make something to use, the less likely it will be misused. Make everything as obvious as possible.